# error in converting xml to table postgresql 9.2

Tags: xml, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following function for converting  xml data in a Postgresql table written in plpgsql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inicio_actualizacion(dato xml)
 RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    VAR TEXT;   
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM p11;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tempinicio AS 
    WITH xml_import (xml_data) AS ( 
    SELECT XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT'||quote_literal(dato)||')),otemp1 AS ( SELECT 
    UNNEST(XPATH('||quote_literal('/pl:entrada/pl:row')||', xml_data, 
    ARRAY[array['||quote_literal('pl')||', '||quote_literal('http://xxx.yy.zz/')||']])) AS vector
    FROM xml_import)
    SELECT CAST((XPATH('||quote_literal('/row/p3c1/text()')||', vector)::VARCHAR[])[1] AS integer) AS p1c1,
    XMLPARSE(CONTENT (XPATH('||quote_literal('/row/p3c3/text()')||', vector)::VARCHAR[])[1]) AS p1c2 '
    ||'FROM otemp1';
    INSERT INTO p11 SELECT * FROM tempinicio;
    RETURN '00';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

When I execute this function in Postgres version 9.2 with the table `entrada`:

```
entrada (p3c1 integer, p3c3xml)
```

containing the following two rows:

```
1;"<![CDATA[<a>a123b</a>]]>"
2;"<b>c345d</b>"
```

I get following results for p11:

```
P11(p1c1 integer, p1c2 xml)
1;"&lt;a&gt;a123b&lt;/a&gt;"
2;NULL
```

But the correct result should be:

```
1;”<a>a123b</a>”
2;NULL
```

As can be seen, the characters `<` and `>` are substituted incorrectly for   `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

Comment: Hi barrera. You could look up html entities &lt; "To display a less than sign (<) we must write: &lt; or &#60;"  "" &gt; ( >) Your results are as you expected Ref  https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your results are as expected.

You could look up html entities `&lt;`

" To display a less than sign (<) we must write: `&lt;` or `&#60;` "

`&gt;` ( >)

Ref  https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp